# Displaying nearest class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div which is hidden until you click the show button. My code works fine for a single instance, the problem is I have this repeated multiple times so it needs to only show the nearest and not use IDs however, I'm not sure how to do this.

Here's my code:

```
<form class="form1">
...
</form>
<a onclick="showDiv()">Show</a>
<div id="show"  style="display:none;">
    <form id="form2">
    '''
    </form>
</div>

*repeated*

<form class="form1">
...
</form>
<a onclick="showDiv()">Show</a>
<div id="show"  style="display:none;">
    <form id="form2">
    '''
    </form>
</div>


<script>
function showDiv() {
   document.getElementById('show').style.display = "block";
}
</script>
```

How can I show the appropriate div to what is clicked?

Update: I want to select by nearest class not nearest sibling

Comment: You should not have 2 `html` elements with the same `id`...

Answer (score 2):

HTML ids are suppose to be unique, which means you can only use it once. You are using the id `show` twice which is only being assigned to the first element because, like I said before, ids are unique and can't be used twice.

I would suggest changing id to class and check `getElementsByClassName` on all the classes named `show` and find the first one that the display is false and make the display true!

Answer (score 0):

If the `div` you want to show is *absolutely always* going to be after the `a` that shows it, you could try this:

```
function showDiv(e){
  e.target.nextElementSibling.style.display='block';
}
```

Comment: thanks for your response - i need to do this by class name and not next sibling and it's not the next a

Answer (score 0):

`document.querySelectorAll('.someClassName')[0]` takes the first element of all element with `someClassName`.
Or if you want to find find div below the element you has been clicked you can

```
function showDiv(event) {
  const clickedElement = event.target;
  clickedElement.nextElementSibling.style.display = 'block';
}
```

Comment: thanks for your response - i need to do this by class name and not next sibling

Answer (score 0):

- id should be unique in your case it's not for div 'show' and form 'form2'
- always use class when you want to repeat an element
- element.closest(this div) will give the expected result

Comment: Added the class 'answer_list' and updated the code to ```<script>
function showDiv() {
   document.closest('answer_list').style.display = "block";
}
</script>``` but it's not working

Answer (score 0):

`id` need to be unique. IN your case you can use [**nextSibling**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nextSibling) to set the display of the immediate next element

```js
function showDiv(elem) {
  elem.nextSibling.style.display = "block"
}
```

```html
<form class="form1">
  ...
</form>
<a onclick="showDiv(this.nextSibling)">Show</a>
<div id="show1" style="display:none;">
  <form id="form21">
    text1
  </form>
</div>


<form class="form1">
  ...
</form>
<a onclick="showDiv(this.nextSibling)">Show</a>
<div id="show2" style="display:none;">
  <form id="form22">
    text2
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for your response - i need to do this by class name and not next sibling